# Passing variables across static tableView cells via CoreData and delegates

Tags: ios, core-data, uitableview

I have a ConfigureTableViewController enabled tableview that has two static cells Users and Locations.
Users tableview cell is connected to ListUserTableViewController via usersSegue. 
Locations tableview cell is connected to LocationTableViewController via segue locationsSegue

ListUserTableViewController has a protocol:

```
    protocol UserSelectionDelegate{
      func userDidSelectUser(userIdentifier:NSString)
    }
```

I select user from ListUserTableViewController and pass it to ConfigureTableViewController, by implementing the delegate UserSelectionDelegate

```
    class ConfigureTableViewController: UITableViewController, UserSelectionDelegate {
    …
    …

    // function pulls user’s fullName from Core Data table based on userIdentifier
    func userDidSelectUser(userIdentifier : NSString) {
    var fetchedResults: [User] = []

    let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

     userIdentifierString = userIdentifier

    do {

        fetchedResults = try context.fetch(User.fetchRequest())
    }
    catch {
        print ("fetch task failed")
    }
    if fetchedResults.count > 0 {

        for user in fetchedResults{
            let aUser:User = user
            if (aUser.uniqueId! == userIdentifierString as String) {
                let fullName = aUser.firstName! + " " + aUser.lastName!
                print("selected user full name: " + (fullName as String))
            }
            else {
                continue
            }
        }
    }

}
}
```

so far so good..

But Now, I want to take the userName pulled from DB and send to to LocationTableViewController via segue locationsSegue

As I transition from ListUserTableViewController to ConfigureTableViewController I have the userName, but when I leave the ConfigureTableViewController and go to LocationTableViewController, I lose the scope of fullName.

I have to somehow store this value of computed fullName in some permanent storage, so Should I put it in a table in CoreData. I want to avoid this, which seems lot of work.

Can I use some kind of delegate chaining so LocationTableViewController can implement a delegate defined in ConfigureTableViewController and pull the data from the other UserSelectionDelegate which has already been implemented and has the fullName in its scope.

Please advise, how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confusing problem statement:

> I lose the scope of fullName

You need to save any changes to the `User` object and retrieve these changes in the next view controller. If the next view controller uses the same `NSManagedObjectContext`, you can also just pass the same `User` object.

Then you have all the data for the full name.

This is commonly implemented as a custom method of the `User` class that inspects its own first and last name and returns a properly formatted string.

Comment: I am trying to pass a User ID along with it, so I can get the user name from the Db though. Your answer gives partial solution. But I will accept it.